# Porque se me repiten los eventos en angular-fullcalendar

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

Estamos desarrollando una aplicación para agendar citas medicas usando full calendar y angularjs

Les generamos un código (render) para que nos muestre en forma de eventos las citas que se guardaron, pero al momento de navegar por el calendario bien sea en las vistas de Mes, Semana o Día me duplica dichos eventos.

```
function  eventScroll(){
    vm.eventSourcees = [];
    var datosCalendario;
    if (vm.fechaInicio !== null && vm.fechaFin !== null){
        Horarios.queryByFechas({
            fechaInicio: $filter('date')(vm.startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', '-0500'),
            fechaFin: $filter('date')(vm.endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', '-0500')
        }).promise.then(function(data){
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                vm.eventSource.push({
                    id: data[i].idHorario,
                    title: data[i].descCita,
                    start: new DAte(data[i].fechaHorario),
                    allDay: false
                 });
        }).catch(function (error){
              console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
function renderView(view){
   vm.startDate = new DAte(view.start);
   vm.endDate = new DAte(view.end);
   console.log('render');
   eventScroll();
}
```

Comment: Hola de primera vista creo que tienes un error en `vm.eventSourcees` creo yo que deberías cambiar la palabra Sourcees por Sources

Comment: Hola Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, es conveniente que modifiques tu pregunta para que la hagas mas legible y entendible, Adicionalmente trata de colocar un ejemplo en funcionamiento del error que tienes para que sea de mayor ayuda.

Comment: Tu código como está actualmente no debería correr. Revisa el ejemplo de código y actualizalo correctamente. Como lo pusiste el ciclo `for` no cierra, la fecha la creas con `DAte` y usas `vm.eventSourcees` en lugar de `vm.eventSources`

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un error tipográfico